# How to invoke a function in a shell script from a Makefile

Tags: shell, makefile, sh

I've a `Makefile` that contains a target to print a given variable:

```
print-%:
    @echo $*=$($*)
```

For example to print the value of variable `CURDIR` I just issue the following command:

```
make print-CURDIR
```

And here's the result:

```
CURDIR=/Users/j3d/Projects/myproject
```

Now I'd like to create a shell script that contains a set of common functions to be invoked from  any `Makefile`... and here's the modified version of the target above:

```
print-%:
    . ./make-util printvar $@
```

And here's `make-util`:

```
#!/bin/sh

printvar()
{
    @echo $*=$(*)
}
```

Finally, running the script above...

```
j3d@j3ds-macbook-pro myproject % make print-CURDIR
```

... doesn't produce the expected result:

```
. ./make-utils CURDIR
```

How should I invoke the script function so that the given variable gets printed correctly?

Comment: You can't.  Makefiles are not shell scripts, and shell scripts are not makefiles.  Make works by FIRST expanding the command to be invoked: it treats it as a text string and expands the variables.  Then, make starts a separate shell process and hands over the expanded text to it, for the shell to run and waits for the shell to exit.  The shell can't access make variables, because it's in a separate process, and there's no way it can "ask" make to provide it some variables (how would that even work?)

Comment: Oh I see... I just wanted to avoid repeating the same tasks over and over again in every Makefile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a suite of make recipes (if you're using GNU make) that you can include and use in multiple makefiles, but you have to do it with *make* syntax, not *shell* syntax, because they are make recipes even if the recipe becomes a shell script after expansion.

You can investigate the GNU make [`define` statement](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Multi_002dLine.html) and [`eval`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Eval-Function.html) and [`call`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Call-Function.html) functions for ways to create user-defined functions in GNU make.  For example you could write a makefile like this:

```
$ cat macros.mk
print-%:
        @echo $*=$($*)
```

then in your other makefiles you could use:

```
include macros.mk
```

and you'd automatically get that rule available.

There are lots and lots of possibilities here but the details depend on what you want to do.

Answer (score 1):

You are nearly there:

Since you are passing the name of the function as first parameter, you could do a

```
#!/bin/sh
printvar()
{
  @echo $*=$(*)
}
"$1"
```

to execute the function. If you want more safety (to catch cases where you pass by mistake some dangerous command instead of a function name), you could do a

```
[ "$1" = printvar ] && printvar
[ "$1" = other_function ] && other_function
```

instead.

If you want to process your script Make-variables, you can pass them as additional parameters:

```
func=$1
shift
[ "$func" = printvar ] && printvar "$@"
[ "$func" = other_function ] && other_function "$@"
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Perhaps I'm missing something as when I run `make print-CURDIR` I get these 2 errors: `./make-utils: line 5: Makefile: command not found` and `./make-utils: line 5: @echo: command not found`. I've tried all the options you mentioned.

Comment: You have in your shell script a command, which says `@echo`. This means that the shell expects an executable file of the name `@echo` in your PATH. Perhaps you meant just `echo`?

Comment: @j3d : Also I don't understand the argument of your statement, `$*=$(*)`. What is this supposed to do? But all this is not related to your original question, which was only _how to invoke a function inside a shell script_. If you have additional problems with your script, please ask a new question here on [so]. Note that one question is expected to focus on one single problem only.

Comment: Why is this marked as an accepted answer?  It doesn't at all answer the question asked.  The request was to take a make recipe (and by extension, a set of such recipes) and put them into shell script functions so they could be invoked by many make recipes.  That's not possible.

Comment: @MadScientist: The information about passing Make variables was added later. The initial question was _how to invoke a **function** from a shell script and pass it parameters_. I explained this in my comment to the OP and suggested that he asks a different question for it, but also extended my answer to mention the usage with a Makefile. Actually, as soon as you can pass *any* parameters from a makefile to a script, it is trivial to have the script forward it to a function defined inside this script, so I don't see a real problem here.